# jsfiddle で、HTML などの全文が欲しいのですが、どのようにすればよいでしょうか

Tags: javascript

jsfiddle で公開されているサンプルソースがあるのですが、
ライブラリのinclude方法や、onloadでの呼び出しなど、詳細まで
理解しておきたいので、
HTML全文をみたいのですが、どのようにすれば、そのような内容を見ることができるでしょうか？

jsfiddle には、まだアカウント登録していませんが、
アカウント登録すれば可能でしょうか？

よろしくおねがいします。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JSFiddle自体にそのような機能は用意されていませんが、実行結果を表示している部分はインラインフレームなので、例えばChromeだと

- 結果が表示されている部分を右クリックして「フレームのソースを表示」
- 結果が表示されている部分を右クリック→検証などとして開発者ツールを開き、iframeタグまでさかのぼり、その直下にあるhtmlタグを右クリック→Copy→Copy outerHTML

  [image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

などの方法でHTMLを取得することができます。JSFiddle用に若干CSSやスクリプトが追加されているようですが、まあ見ればわかると思います。

一応スクリプトの読み込むタイミングなども指定はできますが、動けばいいというぐらいで書かれている可能性もあります。JSFiddleのサンプルの本命はHTML/JS/CSSのコード本体と考え、それ以外の部分はライブラリのドキュメントや、HTML形式で公開されているサンプルがないか確認してみるといいかもしれません。何もなければ、自由に読み込めばよいのでしょうし。

---

おまけ。URLのドメインを `jsfiddle.net` から `fiddle.jshell.net` に変更して、以下のコードを開発者ツールのコンソールで実行すると、HTMLをコピーできます。やってることは上で説明したのと同じです。やっつけなのでいつまで動くかわかりませんが。

```
copy(document.querySelector('iframe').contentDocument.documentElement.innerHTML)
```

Comment: ありがとうございます。大変感謝です。

Comment: コピーしても動かないなー。と調べてみたところ、

<script type="text/javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.0.js"></script>
というところが、https:を付属すると、動きました。
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.0.js"></script>
これですね。

JavaScriptは手慣れてないので、当たり前のところが、当たり前にわからないというのがなかなか大変です。

非常に助かりました。ありがとうございます。

Comment: @s.yamamoto `//` で始まるURLはページと同じURIスキーム(httpとかhttpsとか）を使うという書き方ですね。httpやhttpsでHTMLを読み込んでいればそれと同じものが使われるはずですが、ローカルのHTML(file://)などではうまく動かないと思います。

Comment: な・る・ほ・ど！！！ありがとうございます！

Answer (score 1):

- jsfiddleにログイン
- fiddleを閲覧
- Run
- https://jsfiddle.net/draft/ にアクセス

とすると、RESULT のみが表示されます

Comment: コメントの内容を反映しました.

Comment: ありがとうございます。jsfiddleのログイン作って試して試してみます。助かります。